# How to show some animation while control is rendering?

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, listbox, rendering

I have WPF `ListBox` that shows a lot of data. I need smooth scrolling, so I've set `ListBox.ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll` to False that disables virtualization. Now when I open the tab where this `ListBox` is placed, I see nothing for few seconds because `ListBox` is loading/creating items/rendering. I also have a control that shows some animation that indicates that application is running and user should wait a bit.

How can I show this control while `ListBox` is not available?

Comment: perhaps more details would be helpful?  Things like... what language and framework you're working in... Unfortunately terms like "ListBox" are used in a lot of places.

Comment: how many items do u have in the list?

Comment: Let it be about 500 items. There is listbox with inner itemscontrols.

Comment: do you know which phase of "loading", "creating items" and "rendering" is taking all the time?

Comment: Its hard to say.. WPF Performance Suite shows that most expensive is "Unlabeled Time", than goes "Rendering Thread", but it is uses 5 times less CPU; other categories are not significant.

Answer (score 2):

Add a Grid in the location of your list box and place inside it your ListBox and your animation control. This way they are placed in the same location. The animation control should be on the top of the z-order and so displayed. Once the ListBox has finished loading you would then hide the animation control and so the ListBox would show instead. Any time you need to perform another long operation you set the animation control to visible again.

Comment: How to determine that listbox has already rendered? And rendering is performed in the same thread that "animates" animation, so there won't be any effect. Or I'm not right?  
I'm already using this technique, but when I need to show that some long background (that works in another thread) operation (non-gui) is in progress.

Answer (score 0):

[Clean shutdown in Silverlight and WPF applications](https://web.archive.org/web/20200109071518/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/lbugnion/archive/2009/10/18/clean-shutdown-in-silverlight-and-wpf-applications.aspx)

Check how the author of this application did it via code maybe it can help you though it is different scenario.